# Output in Sublime Text console

Tags: java, c, sublimetext

I use windows.
I wrote a java code in sublime and pressed ctrl+B.
The sublime console displayed the compilation time.
The output of the code was in a cmd window.
It is same in case of c program too.

How do i get the output to display in the sublime console itself?

Comment: I assume you mean `Build Output Panel` and not `Console`, because in Sublime the console is a distinct thing. The `sublime-build` file that you use controls where the output goes; it sounds like you're using a custom build that opens a command prompt instead.

Comment: sorry my bad. I am new to sublime. Yes, I want the output in the Build Output Panel. Yes, I used a custom build. Is there any way I can modify it to achieve this? I used REPL for python to give output in a new window. Is that possible for java and c too?

Comment: Generically your build can execute any program you want, so you can construct a build that opens an external terminal and asks it to run your program. You can also use the Terminus package to run an interactive program directly in Sublime.  That doesn't answer your original question though, which is to not use a custom build that does that.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what i wanted. How do I get terminus and other stuff? Thanks. Very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can install https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus and get an integrated terminal on sublime text.

Comment: That's not what the question was asking.

Comment: I installed Terminus. Now, what?

Comment: You get a terminal. Go ahead and use it.

Comment: I don't know how to combine the terminus to sublime build output panel